# Fermat little theorem fails in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, primes, modulo, number-theory

I'm currently trying to write a program in MATLAB which checks if a number `n` is prime or not. For starters I'm implementing the [Fermat Primality Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test).

Fermat states that for a prime `p` and `1 <= b < p`:

```
b^(p-1) = 1  (mod p)
```

So in MATLAB with `p = 17`, and `b = 11`

```
>> mod(b^(p-1),p)
```

or

```
>> rem(b^(p-1),p)
```

Problem I have is that for this instance MATLAB returns `0`. However if `p` is prime it should return `1`. I cannot see what I'm missing, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: btw I see no indication about how [`isprime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isprime.html) is implemented in MATLAB. The algorithm you mentioned is stated in the [MuPAD function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/isprime.html) doc page (part of Symbolic Math Toolbox) not the one in core MATLAB..

Comment: You are right on that Amro, if a = c, it does not always mean b = c :) I've removed the post-script from the question as it does not any value. Also thanks for your clear explanation below!

Answer (score 9):

@James gave a correct explanation, I just wanted to expand a bit more.

You see in [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), integers in the range `[2^52,2^53]` are exactly representable (that's because we have 52+1 bits for the fraction part). In the next range `[2^53,2^54]`, integers representable are the even ones (previous range multiplied by two). And so on for the next ranges where the spacing doubles every time we go higher.

The number `11^16` (which equals `45949729863572161`) unfortunately is not exactly representable in double-precision. In fact the list of representable numbers around that one is:

```
45949729863572144
45949729863572152
45949729863572160
45949729863572168
45949729863572176
```

According to rounding mode, `45949729863572161` will be approximated by the closest representable number which is in this case `45949729863572160`.

To understand what happens, let's try to store the numbers `45949729863572100 + [44:76]` and display the result:

```
% build a cell array of strings containing the numbers, then convert to doubles
% (you could also enter the numbers as literals directly)
str = cellstr(num2str((44:76)', '459497298635721%d'));
num = str2double(str);

% print the original number, its stored value (in decimal and hex notations)
for i=1:numel(num)
    fprintf('%s %17.0f %bX\n', str{i}, num(i), num(i));
end
```

Here is the output (with some annotations):

```
    actual           stored          stored in HEX
----------------------------------------------------
45949729863572144 45949729863572144 436467E125C16356    % exact representation
45949729863572145 45949729863572144 436467E125C16356
45949729863572146 45949729863572144 436467E125C16356
45949729863572147 45949729863572144 436467E125C16356
45949729863572148 45949729863572144 436467E125C16356
45949729863572149 45949729863572152 436467E125C16357
45949729863572150 45949729863572152 436467E125C16357
45949729863572151 45949729863572152 436467E125C16357
45949729863572152 45949729863572152 436467E125C16357    % exact representation
45949729863572153 45949729863572152 436467E125C16357
45949729863572154 45949729863572152 436467E125C16357
45949729863572155 45949729863572152 436467E125C16357
45949729863572156 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572157 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572158 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572159 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572160 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358    % exact representation
45949729863572161 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572162 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572163 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572164 45949729863572160 436467E125C16358
45949729863572165 45949729863572168 436467E125C16359
45949729863572166 45949729863572168 436467E125C16359
45949729863572167 45949729863572168 436467E125C16359
45949729863572168 45949729863572168 436467E125C16359    % exact representation
45949729863572169 45949729863572168 436467E125C16359
45949729863572170 45949729863572168 436467E125C16359
45949729863572171 45949729863572168 436467E125C16359
45949729863572172 45949729863572176 436467E125C1635A
45949729863572173 45949729863572176 436467E125C1635A
45949729863572174 45949729863572176 436467E125C1635A
45949729863572175 45949729863572176 436467E125C1635A
45949729863572176 45949729863572176 436467E125C1635A    % exact representation
```

As you can see there can be no numbers in between `xxx44` and `xxx52` (since their HEX representation only differ in the last bit by one). Anything in between will have to be approximated to the nearest representable number. So the range is divided by two, half assigned to the lower bound, the other half assigned to the upper bound (note that there are 7 numbers in between, so the middle one is a special case, and gets assigned to the upper/lower bounds in an alternating fashion).

As a result, entering any number between `45949729863572156` and `45949729863572164` (which includes `11^16`) will actually store the double-value `45949729863572160`.

---

Now others have suggested using a [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library to avoid these numerical limitations (the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) from MathWorks, [VPI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) or [HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class) by *John D'Errico*, or one of the other solutions available on the File Exchange ...). For example:

```
>> b = sym(11);    % Symbolic Math Toolbox
>> b^16
ans =
45949729863572161
>> mod(b^16,17)
ans =
1
```

However, in your case, [`uint64`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint64.html) is capable of accurately storing those numbers:

```
>> b = uint64(11); p = uint64(17);
>> b^(p-1)
ans =
    45949729863572161
>> mod(b^(p-1),p)
ans =
                    1
```

Just keep in mind that:

```
>> intmax('uint64')
ans =
 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 2):

Individual integers can only be represented "continuously" up to `2^53` by doubles. `11^16` is greater than this, and therefore an approximation is used. To perform this calculation you would have to use an arbitrary precision integer data structure. [Here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) is one add-on that does this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to rounding of floats. This is the help section on `mod`.

```
EDU>> help mod

MOD    Modulus after division.
MOD(x,y) is x - n.*y where n = floor(x./y) if y ~= 0.  If y is not an
integer and the quotient x./y is within roundoff error of an integer,
then n is that integer.  The inputs x and y must be real arrays of the
same size, or real scalars.

The statement "x and y are congruent mod m" means mod(x,m) == mod(y,m).

By convention:
   MOD(x,0) is x.
   MOD(x,x) is 0.
   MOD(x,y), for x~=y and y~=0, has the same sign as y.

Note: REM(x,y), for x~=y and y~=0, has the same sign as x.
MOD(x,y) and REM(x,y) are equal if x and y have the same sign, but
differ by y if x and y have different signs.

See also rem.

Overloaded methods:
   sym/mod

Reference page in Help browser
   doc mod
```

This does seem strange to implement mod with `floor(x./y)` in MATLAB, but I am reasonably confident that is why.

EDIT: I believe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) can help you.